# How to calculate the posterior belief in bayes-optimal-privacy?

Tags: privacy, anonymity

The paper "[L-diversity: privacy beyond k-anonymity](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/infolab/Data/Courses/CS632/2016/2015/2014/Papers/gehrke-ldiversity-icde06.pdf)" (DOI: [10.1109/ICDE.2006.1](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICDE.2006.1)) introduces the concept of bayes-optimal privacy and the idea of prior and posterior belief.
A formula for calculating the *posterior belief* is given:

[image: formula for posterior belief]]

The paper states:

> let [image: conditional probability of s conditioned on q] be the conditional probability of the sensitive
> attribute conditioned on the fact that the nonsensitive attribute Q
> can be generalized to [image: q with star]

**How can I calculate the example below?**

Given the table in figure 1 (`T`) and the generalized version in figure 2 (`T*`), what is the result for e.g. [image: posterior belief for ((13053, 28, russian), heart disease, T*)]?

How can I calculate the values for the conditional probabilities `f(s|q)`, `f(s|q*)`?

[image: Figure 1. Inpatient microdata]
[image: Figure 2. 4-anonymous Inpatient microdata]

Comment: Please elaborate on what purpose this **actually** serves...?

Comment: @J It's about calculating bounds on anonymization of datasets. As always, the point is to be able to analyze the dataset without disclosing identifying information.

Comment: OP. Please add some more context to question (shown above) such that people have a better chance or parsing and answering you correctly.